# What does this mean: "Bruh you folded like a house of cards."

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms, slang

I got this reply using Youtube.

I think 'Bruh' means 'Bro', and 'you folded like a house of cards' means like 'you crashed them'.

Is this right?

Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_cards

Comment: @HotLicks I do know what 'House of cards' mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The import of the message is that "You, my bro, collapsed completely, utterly."

This is a combination of two idioms.

"Fold like a cheap suitcase" meaning collapse easily and so be unreliable.
This eventually became *Fold like a cheap Suit*.

From thefreedictionary.com
[fold like a cheap suitcase](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fold+like+a+cheap+suitcase)
Collapse easily. Expensive luggage was made, as now, from well-constructed leather or fabric. Cheap ones used to be made of cardboard with little or no structural reinforcement. You'd also hear “***Fold like a cheap suit***,” but since fabric folds easily, whether it's cashmere or polyester, “suitcase” presents a better connotation of a losing proposition.

Other sources mention "..like a cheap *Tent*"

This combined with the idea of a House of Cards
also from thefreedictionary.com

[a house of cards](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+house+of+cards)
A plan, organization, or other entity that is destined to fail due to a weak structure or foundation (likened to a literal house of cards, which is built by balancing playing cards against one another, and is very easily toppled).

Folding a hand at cards is a considered decision. Folding like a cheap suitcase or cloth suit or house of cards cannot be avoided or delayed by any amount of determination no matter how it breaks your brother's heart.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, 'Bruh' means 'Bro,' but 'you folded like a house of cards' does not mean, 'you crashed them,' or at least it means more than that.

'Folded' refers to giving up on what appears to be a bad hand (of cards or anything you posses).  'House of cards' refers to a house built with playing cards--a game played for fun, but the object of the game is to build the house so it won't fall down...but it inevitably does...and when it does, it's quite a spectacle.

So, when you combine the two terms, it means you gave up in a spectacular manner on what might have been a winning hand...but it was inevitable...because you don't have enough confidence in yourself.

It is an indirect way of saying, have more confidence in yourself and maybe next time you will do much better.